# Keyboard auto-hides on iOS when typing in a ListView's TextField element

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm working on a NativeScript app and I've setup a ListView element to hold dynamically generated TextField elements. When I start typing in one of the ListView's Textfield elements on iOS, it closes the keyboard immediately.

This behavior only happens on iOS and not on the Android version of the application. I found an forum post about this type of issue happening with iOS in a NativeScript Vue application but I'm unsure how to use what they did to help me with Angular.

https://github.com/nativescript-vue/nativescript-vue/issues/334

```
component.html

 <StackLayout formArrayName="ingredients" row="5" colSpan="3">
                        <ListView height="100" [items]="form.get('ingredients').value">                           
                            <ng-template
                                let-ingredient="item"
                                let-i="index"
                            >
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <TextField 
                                        hint="Add Ingredient"                                       
                                        width="300"
                                        [formControlName]="i"                                    
                                    ></TextField>
                                </StackLayout>                                
                            </ng-template>                                    
                        </ListView>                                           
                    </StackLayout>   

component.ts

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({  
      name: new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur'}),
      description: new FormControl(null, {updateOn: 'blur'}),
      ingredients: new FormArray([new FormControl(null)]),
      steps: new FormArray([new FormControl(null)]),
      imageNames: new FormArray([])
    });  
  }

  onAddIngredient() {
    const control = new FormControl(null);
    (<FormArray>this.form.get('ingredients')).push(control);
  }
```

Playground: [Playground version of app](https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.70433296.1233189991.1554133729-380207986.1552317443&template=play-ng&id=XznOEP&v=4)

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager ? That should fix the issue for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. I put it on NativeScript playground here: https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.70433296.1233189991.1554133729-380207986.1552317443&template=play-ng&id=XznOEP&v=4